# How to Right Align \attrib in Verse Package?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, verse

This MWE comes straight from Peter Wilson's Verse Package manual (v2.4b).
In the example the attribution is right justified. [image: Right Justified Attribution]

However, when I implement the MWE in MikTex my attribution is left justified.

[image: Left Justified attribution]

How do I right justify the attribution?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{verse}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\poemtitle{Fleas}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{What a funny thing is a flea}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
What a funny thing is a flea. \\
You can't tell a he from a she. \\
But he can. And she can. \\
Whoopee! \\
\end{verse}
\attrib{Anonymous}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\attrib` is not defined by default. You'll note the [`verse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/verse) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/verse/verse.pdf) mentions (section **3.4 Examples**, p 9, just before the "Fleas example"):

> It is left up to you how you might want to add information about
>    the author of a poem. Here is one example of a macro for this:
>
> ```
> \newcommand{\attrib}[1]{%
>   \nopagebreak{\raggedleft\footnotesize #1\par}}
> ```

So, let's do that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}

\newcommand{\attrib}[1]{%
  \nopagebreak{\raggedleft\footnotesize #1\par}}
\begin{document}

\poemtitle{Fleas}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{What a funny thing is a flea}
\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
  What a funny thing is a flea. \\
  You can't tell a he from a she. \\
  But he can. And she can. \\
  Whoopee! \\
\end{verse}
\attrib{Anonymous}

\end{document}
```